# Cannot maintain macro: Effect of maximizing specific macros

Tags: diet

I am trying to maintain my nutrition at 1800 cal with the following macro ratios:

```
Carb: 40%
Fat: 30%
Protein: 30%
```

However, at the end of the day, it looks the like the follows:

```
Carb: 32.5%
Fat: 42.5%
Protein: 25%
```

My question is that in such a case, would higher carb or higher fat affect my body negatively (keeping the protein constant)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is no, it won't impact you negatively in any possible imaginable way.

Why do you care so much about your macro nutrition ratio in the first place ? there's no real evidence that 10% or 15% more of this or that makes any difference on your health, it'd rater be more beneficial if you completely stop measuring your macros and actually begin measuring your micro nutrients, your water intake and sleep.

''When eating a balanced diet based on fresh and non processed food, you don't have to worry about your macros''-Alexander Leonidas

The only real difference you will get from macro nutrients is when you are trying to lose weight because higher protein makes you feel fuller so you eat less. Any other little benefit or side effect you get from playing around with your macros is purely personal and most likelly just placebo.

Comment: Fair answer, but you call out one thing to be "personal and only based on anecdotal experience" and then add a quote of Alexander Leonidas? I couldn't find anything that shows he is a scientist is has done any scientific research.

Comment: with the phrase  "personal and only based on anecdotal experience" i meant that any benefit or negative thing you get from playing with your macros percentage is personal.

Comment: This is a bad answer based on supposition. You have no idea what *kind* of food the OP is eating, and you staunchly declare that a diet consisting of almost 50% calories from fat won't "impact you negatively in any possible imaginable way"? You also state that the percentages have no difference on health, that is also supposition based on extremely scant information.

Comment: where do you see me ever mentioning a diet based of 50% of calories from fat? false accusation based on nothing. I was speaking about what the user who asked the question suggested which was a rough difference of 10%. As he suggested from 30% to 42% or 40% to 32%. Are you going to tell me 12% more fat or 8% more carbs will save or ruin your life ?

Comment: I never said percentages have nothing to do with health ,  i simply said that if you eat a healthy varied diet , you don't have to worry about macros. Does this to you translate to ''drink oil and nothing else and you'll be fine'' or ''eat only bread''. Did i probably said something along the line ''eat whatever you find it doesn't matter'' ?